# How can i get values from 2 lists and put them into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists

```
list1 = ["ben", "tim", "john", "wally"]
list2 = [18,12,34,55]
```

the output im looking for is this

```
[{'Name': 'ben', 'Age': 18, 'Name': 'tim', 'Age': 12, 'Name': 'john', 'Age': 34, 'Name': 'wally', 'Age': 55}]
```

Comment: The output you're looking for is invalid since dictionaries can't have duplicate keys.  Perhaps you meant a list of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks, i forgot that keys in a dictionary need to be unique

Comment: @CodingOwl - do you need to revise your problem description to make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary; even your output snippet would just return `[{'Name': 'wally', 'Age': 55}]`

[image: opret]

---

However, **`{k: v for k, v in zip(list1, list2)}`** will return

```py
{'ben': 18, 'tim': 12, 'john': 34, 'wally': 55}
```

---

And **`[{'Name': n, 'Age': a} for n, a in zip(list1, list2)]`** will return

```py
[{'Name': 'ben', 'Age': 18},
 {'Name': 'tim', 'Age': 12},
 {'Name': 'john', 'Age': 34},
 {'Name': 'wally', 'Age': 55}]
```